# Дизайн меню методами CSS

Tags: css

Может подскажет кто, как методами CSS сделать так, чтобы при наведении на меню подсвечивалось плавно, т.е текст не резко менял цвет а с течением времени?

Answer (score 4):

Есть [кроссбраузерное решение](http://www.tigir.com/fade.htm) на javascript. И есть [некроссбраузерное решение](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/) на css3. Выбирать вам. =)

Comment: Эм, это всё хорошо, конечно... но почему не подключить jQuery? На мой взгляд, вариант разумнее!

Comment: Это разумно, если на сайте используется jQuery. А если нет?

Comment: А если нет, то можно начать его использовать, либо, если имеется другая библиотека - использовать ее =)

Comment: IE давно выкинуть пора, лично я не понимаю что держит IE на плаву ... тупые пользователи которые не могут установить более удобный и эффективней броузер ?

Comment: @shurik а фаерфокс секретарша через telnet скачать должна?)

Comment: Я вот почитал вчера про css3. ТАм говорят, что еще не все браузеры его поддерживают

Comment: @Sh4dow 
1. секретарша ниче ставить не должна. Должен ставить админ.
2. Что бы просто зайти на страницу и скачать что-то можно не заморачиватся по поводу дизайна.